# Django: Combine two Field Inputs to Generate URL to navgate to another Django Template

Tags: python, jquery, django, url

In my Django project there is an index model which renders an index.html view, in which I have a form:

```
          <input type="text" list="option">
          <label >Type or Select Query</label>
            <datalist id="option">
                <option value= "​Option 1">
                <option value= "​Options 2">
            </datalist>
<div class="input-field">
    <select>
      <option value="view_function1">Text 1</option>
      <option value="view_function2">Text 2</option>
    </select>
    </div>
```

What I want to do is take the text input / option selection in the text field and merge it with the option selected in the drop down field to form something like this:

/view_fucntion2/Option 1 or
/view_function1/query

These urls would serve the various models in a template defined in views.py. The query + drop down merge will execute on a button submit.

I understand I may be able to achieve this with Jquery, but my grasp of that is limited. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

While you should be using the `form.is_valid()` method, this is an option if you don't know how to use Django Forms:

```
# on form POST 
if request.method == 'POST':

    # get posted values 
    var_1 = request.POST.get('var_1', '')
    var_2 = request.POST.get('var_2', '')

    # redirect to new URL
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/%s/%s/' % (var_1, var_2))
```